# aspect is not invoked

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect

I've got a simple `aspect` that supposed to set the value of class fied, that has annotation `@GuiceInject`.

Originally I have this

```
@GuiceInject(module=RepositoryModule.class)
private IRacesRepository repository;
```

And I expect to get similar to this

```
private IRacesRepository repository = GuiceInject.getInstance(IRacesRepository.class);
```

And here is my aspect

```
public aspect InjectionAspect {

    Object around(): get(@GuiceInject * *) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
        // instantiate object as it supposed to be null originally
        return GuiceInjector.getInstance(thisJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
    }
}
```

As far as I understand - I am new to AOP - it supposed to replace `get` invokations of the field with the code in aspect.

It compiles fine, but when I run the application - nothing happens. I get `NullPointerException` for `readRaces` method as it stays `null` so `aspect` did not work.

My `main` class looks like this

```
public class Example {
    @GuiceInject(module=RepositoryModule.class)
    private IRacesRepository racesRepository;

    private void execute() {
        System.out.println("List of races: " + racesRepository.readRaces());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().execute();
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Annotation has this definition

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
// make annotation visible in runtime for AspectJ
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GuiceInject {
    Class<? extends AbstractModule> module();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to redefine pointcut syntax as

```
Object around(): get(@package.subpackage.GuiceInject * *.*)
```

Correct field signature must specify the type of the field, the declaring type, and name. If your annotation is in different package, it should be fully qualified.

Comment: changed nothing

Comment: @user1432980
Try to fully qualify annotation `@package.subpackage.GuiceInject`

Comment: Whoa, it helped. It started to work (though I got `nullpointer` but it is at least displayed aspect in the exception message)

Comment: Glad I could help. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: `Idea` with plugins + also `gradle` with plugin for aspectj

Comment: I see, did not try that yet, but I find Eclipse Aspect J Development Tools useful, just in case you will use Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, I heard of it, they also have a good documentation for aspects